# Received 405 (Method Not Allowed) on PATCH request via AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am attempting to use an AJAX call to update user entries via a form using Laravel 5.2. When I submit the form without AJAX, the new entries go into the database like they are supposed to, but if I try it via a PATCH AJAX request, I receive a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error.

Here is the first line of my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ProjectsController@foo', 1]]) !!}
```

And here is the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax
({
    url: '/foo/update/1',
    type: 'PATCH',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert('inside AJAX function');
        console.log('inside AJAX leader button');
    }
});
```

When I try to change the method type to PUT, I receive the same error and when I change it to PUT/PATCH, the AJAX call is NOT triggered. When I change the method to POST I get received an error 500, method not found exception because the update method is not a post method.
I used this line to create all of the RESTful methods:

```
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

I know that I could try to make it work using a POST method, but I would like to understand PATCH more. If you have any information that would help me solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the endpoint doesn't allow PATCH requests. According to RFC 2016, there should also be an `Allowed` header returned, with a list of allowed methods of requests, so check that one out and you'll figure out which methods you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Patch requires a body; If you're updating a record you would need to provide a body for Patch. In your case it could be an empty object!